# Recuperar datos de un Campo de texto en un Informe con VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

solicitando su ayuda con este pequeño problema con VBA
Lo que sucede es que necesito saber el dato de un campo de texto que se encuentra en un informe, y si es igual a 0, entonces cambiar su propiedad de visible, para que no se vea, para eso utilizo:

Me.ModAgrego.Visible = False

Para hacerlo visible o no me funciona perfectamente, pero necesito hacer una condicion para saber si se muestra o no, mi primera version fue esta:

```
If Me.ModAgrego.value = 0 Then
 Me.ModAgrego.Visible = False
Else
 Me.ModAgrego.Visible = True
End If
```

Estoy seguro de que la condicion es correcta, de lo que se que esta mal es de como estoy evaluando el datos, es decir, esta parte: Me.ModAgrego.value = 0

Lo intente tambien con [ModAgrego] = 0, pero tampoco funciona, agradeceria que pudieran ayudarme con esto

Comment: Ese campo de texto entiendo que obtiene su valor de una consulta, no?. Lo que tendrías que hacer es evaluar el valor de ese campo en la propia consulta, justo antes de generar el informe.  Y dependiendo del valor generas el informe mostrando o no ese campo .

Si pones la consulta de datos que utilizas y cómo estás mostrando el informe te podremos ayudar más pero aporta pocos datos cómo para sacar conclusiones.

Comment: Como te dice @dogwall el error no lo tienes en el if.

Probando tu código en un formulario con un botón y un textBox tu código me funciona perfectamente